# Availability Schedule field in Django Models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

I am quite new to Django and I'm trying to build a web application where some users will be able to input their available weekly schedule and also show at what times of a day they are available. The picture below(this is just front-end part) shows something similar to what I'm trying to build. What type of Model field do I use to store this type of information inside of a Model class?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use a ManyToMany field which links to a `Shift` table.

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    # Day of week
    day = models.CharField()
    # Morning, afternoon, evening
    time = models.CharField()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    availability = models.ManyToManyField(Shift)
```

The Django docs have a handy guide on using ManyToManyFields.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0):

Now that I look at it I can try to create many [MultiSelect](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/) fields for each of the days(Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,...Saturday) and each of them will have 3 choices(Morning, Afternoon, Evening). This way you wouldn't need to prepopulate the database(before using the database) with all different options(Sunday Morning,Monday Evening etc.) However, I might run into the trouble of having redundancy in my table in the long run.